# My pyinstaller is giving Assertion Error when I execute it

Tags: python, api, pyinstaller

Running other scripts gives no problem. Something about package distribution is raising the exception.

I am able to successfully execute and create .exe files from other scripts, even previous version of this script.

My python version is 3.7 and pyinstaller version is 3.4. Running on Windows 10 64-bit OS.

Thanks in advance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 241, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 521, in assemble
    deps_proc = DependencyProcessor(self.graph, additional_files_cache)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\toc_conversion.py", line 49, in __init__
    self._distributions.update(self._get_distribution_for_node(node))
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\toc_conversion.py", line 86, in _get_distributi
on_for_node
    assert len(dists) == 1
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was that I installed few modules right there from their download directory and didn't move them to the ".../site-packages" directory, so PyInstaller wasn't able to find them.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? It seems I'm facing the same problem. Thx.